# Нормализация БД или удобство запросов?

Tags: sql, поиск, полнотекстовый-поиск

Подскажите пожалуйста, например у нас есть сайт с описанием автомобилей. Возьмём один из них: описание Porsche 911 GT2 992. У нас будут повторяться и марка и модель и номер кузова, поэтому их мы выведем в отдельные таблицы, как рекомендовано это делать, и в конце концов из БД мы сможем получить, что-то такое:

Porsche | 911 | GT2 | 992 |описание

А теперь представим, что пользователь ищет описание для этого автомобиля через наш поиск.

И отправляет через поиск “Porsche 911”

У нас нет ни в одной ячейки БД «porsche 911» нам нужно вначале обьединить 4 колонки и уже потом делать поиск. Но это как-то не изящно для 2021 года. Если запихать марку, модель, номер кузова в одну ячейку - то это как-то не правильно с точки зрения нормализации, да и фильтровать например по марке или кузову станет сложнее. Как быть? Есть 3-й сценарий? Полнотекстовый поиск? Или это дорого для такого случая?

Comment: Ожидать от почтенных стареньких технологий изящества 2021 года не стоит, но с точки зрения интерфейса пользователя, проще ему предлагать выбор через dropdown/combobox меню. Ну или объединять четыре колонки (возможно view и индексы) т.к. это как раз обратная сторона нормализации.

Comment: А mysql может объединить ячейки и ещё поискать с помощью LIKE уже по объединённым ячейкам? Или MySQL только объеденит, отдаст, а искать я уже буду не при помощи БД, а например уже Javascript’ом по массиву (indexOf например). И ещё вопрос, какой набор джентельмена для следующий задачи: библиотека. Книги, журналы, классическая библиотека как у вас в городе. Нужна четкая структура для хранения. Реляционная БД или noSQL в 2021 году?

Comment: ПО опыту, чем данные более атомарны/уникальны/неделимы, тем проще с ними работать. Проще объединить поля, чем в последствии их парсить из одного поле. Можно сделать объединяющее представление или обновляемую связанную таблицу при необходимости. Объединять имеет смысл только при какой-то лютой оптимизации на огромном массиве.

Comment: Можно и с помощью БД `car_mark.name || car_model.name || car_cnumber.name || car_number.name like 'porche 100%'`. И если вы не знаете, зачем вам точно нужен noSQL, то определенно реляционная БД. Хотя можете в качестве эксперимента попробовать mongo, там вроде есть возможность объединять коллекции в более-менее понятном виде.

Answer (score 0):

Объединять все в одну ячейку не стоит, т.к. это не будет работать, если пользователь скажем введет не "Porsche 911", а "911 Porsche". Наверняка, вы захотите, чтоб в этом случае тоже находился результат.

И тут без полнотекстового поиска не обойтись. Можно использовать встроенный или внешний (типа solr или elasticsearch).

Для встроенного это может выглядеть так:

```
create table auto (manufacturer text, model text, body text);
insert into auto values ('Porsche', '911 GT', '992');

=> SELECT * from auto where to_tsvector('english', manufacturer || ' ' ||  model || ' ' ||  body) @@ to_tsquery(E'\'Porsche 992\'');
 manufacturer | model  | body
--------------+--------+------
 Porsche      | 911 GT | 992
(1 row)
```

можно создать индекс, для того чтобы данные парсились один раз при вставке

```
create index auto_full_text on auto
  using gin(to_tsvector('english', manufacturer || ' ' ||  model || ' ' ||  body));
```